# How use forall in bit-vector

Tags: z3, smt

I intend to do is go all the vector, and do different things on each bit.

What I want to know is if I'm doing well forall (in `define-fun LT....`)?

Because the results do not match the expected: S

Code found in this link: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/xrFK

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the intended semantics of your formula is, but intuitively it seems that your definition of `is_in` may be the culprit:

```
(define-fun is_in ((e (_ BitVec 9)) (S (_ BitVec 9))) Bool
    ;; True if e is an element of the "set" S.
    (= (bvand e S) e))
```

The constraint `(= (bvand e S) e))` means that this function can only return true when `S` is equal to `e`. Going by the name of the function, I would expect the definition to be `(not (= (bvand e S) Empty))`.